# How do I make an interface like this

Tags: android-layout

This interface is a curriculum , the top row shows a week , the left-most line shows the time , the other is to be on this week 's lesson , the background color of different courses are different , how can I go to make such an interface ?

[image]

if I use `Gridlayout` or `Tablayout`, it will be use too many `TextView`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `GridView` with different row item (first row & first column are different) and use `BottomNavigation` or `TabLayout` for your Tabs at bottom of the screen.